# Dropdown change function with jquery

Tags: jquery, select

I have 3 Select(dropdown).

Let First Dropdown,Second Dropdown and Third Dropdown.
I use jquery change function.
When I change first Dropdown,Second Dropdown is appear.And I Changed second Dropdown.But third Dropdown is not appear.
I don't know Where is wrong.Please Help me.

Html:

```
 <div class='select'>
  <select class='myFirstDropdown' name='first'>
   <option value='1'>1
   <option value='2'>2
   <option value='3'>3
  </select>
 </div>
```

Js:

```
$('.myFirstDropdown').change(function(){
//var result= $(this).val();
    $('.select').append("<select class='secondDropdown' name='second'><option value='second1'>second1<option value='second2'>Second2</select>");
});
$('.secondDropdown').change(function(){
$('.select').append("<select class='thirdDropdown' name='third'><option value='second1'>second1<option value='second2'>Second2</select>");
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w3udj Example Code

Comment: Can you please post your sample Jquery code?

Comment: your example does not match your question. could you please provide us with your full code?

Comment: So Sorry For Wrond Link.Update link is here.http://jsfiddle.net/waiyan112/w3udj/2/

Comment: @WaiYan you can either wait for this to reopen or post a new question with proper code/fiddle

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/Rnf92/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: **[SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rnf92/)**

```
$('.myFirstDropdown').change(function(){
    $('.select').append("<select class='secondDropdown' name='second'><option value='second1'>second1<option value='second2'>Second2</select>");
});

$('.select').on('change', '.secondDropdown', function(){
    $('.select').append("<select class='thirdDropdown' name='third'><option value='second1'>second1<option value='second2'>Second2</select>");
});
```

Your second select box is added dynamically and therefore event should be attached using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)...